# Pulling nested collection properties into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, lodash

I have a nested array like this:

```
const columns = [
    {
        sections: [
            {
                file: 'type-grid_1.svg',
                featured: false,
                dimensions: {
                    height: 4442,
                    width: 362
                },
                size: 'small'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        sections: [
            {
                file: 'type-grid_2.svg',
                featured: false,
                dimensions: {
                    height: 4339,
                    width: 362
                },
                size: 'small'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I need to pull all `file` values into an array, like this:

```
['type-grid_1.svg', 'type-grid_2.svg']
```

I tried this but it gives me arrays of arrays:

```
map(columns, (column) => map(column.sections, (section) => section.file))
```

Suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention that `sections` can contain multiple entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With just ES6 you can iterate with a nesting [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and use [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with [array spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to flatten:

```js
const columns = [{"sections":[{"file":"type-grid_1.svg","featured":false,"dimensions":{"height":4442,"width":362},"size":"small"}]},{"sections":[{"file":"type-grid_2.svg","featured":false,"dimensions":{"height":4339,"width":362},"size":"small"}]}];

const result = [].concat(...columns.map(({ sections }) => sections.map((section) => section.file)));

console.log(result);
```

With lodash you can use [`flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flatMapDeep):

```js
const columns = [{"sections":[{"file":"type-grid_1.svg","featured":false,"dimensions":{"height":4442,"width":362},"size":"small"}]},{"sections":[{"file":"type-grid_2.svg","featured":false,"dimensions":{"height":4339,"width":362},"size":"small"}]}];

const { map, flatMap } = _;

const result = flatMap(columns, (column) => map(column.sections, 'file'))


console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I agree, if you're already using lodash for the `map` function, you may as well just switch it out for `flatMap`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `reduce` like so:

```
console.log(columns.reduce((agg, { sections }) => {
      return [...agg, ...sections.map(({ file }) => file)]
}, []));
```

It caters for multiple files in your sections arrays too.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much,

Comment: @BrandonDurham just it is unnecessary expensive, there is absolutely no need for duplicating `agg` on every loop, it's not because its possible that it is a good idea

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one section in each of your sections, like shown above, it's simple:

```
map(columns, col => col.sections[0].file);
```

If there are more, reduce the array of files to a flat array:

```
const res = columns.map(col => col.sections.map(section => section.file))
.reduce((all, current) => all.concat(current), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create the desired flattened array.

I don't think that it really needs [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) seeing you are already using `const` as a variable declaration, so you are probably already using some version of ES6. If there would be a specific need for the library feel free to update your opening posts.

```js
const columns = [{
  sections: [{
    file: 'type-grid_1.svg',
    featured: false,
    dimensions: {
      height: 4442,
      width: 362
    },
    size: 'small'
  }]
}, {
  sections: [{
    file: 'type-grid_2.svg',
    featured: false,
    dimensions: {
      height: 4339,
      width: 362
    },
    size: 'small'
  }]
}];

const result = columns.reduce( (current, item) => current.concat( item.sections.map( section => section.file ) ), []);

console.log( result );
```